# Rotate 6 bit in C language

Tags: c, rotation, mask, bit

I have to read a mask of bits (6 bit) from a file in order to activate some feature in a program in c.
I read the mask in this way:

```
char *val = "100111";
unsigned int mask;
char *endp = NULL;
mask = strtoul(val, &endp, 2);
```

after doing this anyway I have to rotate bits read:

`mask = rol(mask);`

for example if I read this sequence:

100111

it would result in

111001

mask is always 6 bit length.

I need an implementation of rol function working with msvc and gcc.

thanks.

Comment: `111001` is reverse ? rotate left 3bit shift `111100` ?

Comment: This doesn't match any definition of "ROL" I am aware of. Do you mean that you want to reverse the bits?

Answer (score 2):

would this help?

```
unsigned int rol(unsigned int mask) {
    unsigned int ret = 0;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i != 6; ++i) {
        ret |= ((mask >> i) & 0x01) << (5 - i);
    }
    return ret;
}
```